# xdebug mapping setting's in my project php

Tags: php, xdebug

I've been working on setting up correctly my xdebug debugger so I can improve my soft dev process, I manage to get xdebug working with phpstorm for some files that are outside of the project as in the first picture. But when it comes to debug some of the files that are inside of my mvc project (my app folder) I can set my debbuger to work properly and as far as now Im kind of stuck so any help would be welcome.

[image: This is my project folder]

When I debbug phptest.php it work perfectly because it's an easy mapping
But when I need to debbug something like any php script on my controller folder for example, I can't get to there.

[image: This is how I've set up my mappings]

So please any ideas on how to do this.

Regards

Added a new screen shot of my mappings settings as @rafail pointed :)

[image: mapping screen shot]

Comment: are you sure that part of code (were you put your break point) is executed? try to add var_dump("something") and put break point on it. could you see this "something" on the page?

Comment: Nope, it dosn't even reach the page, it just get "loading".

Comment: this usually means that xdebug already connected to something and waits response from it ) what are your xdebug settings? do you have any messages in phpstorm, did you continued previous debug session or stopped?

Comment: I've started a new session and all over again, now my project works as normal but still no xdebug even when I set breakpoints.

Comment: any luck to make it work?

Comment: nope I think it's something about my mvc framework, because it's developed by our team.

Comment: this is not an issue usually ) if code executes it should be possible to debug it ) could you check your mapping settings in Lang & and Framework > PHP > SErvers > YourServer. on the screenshot it looks like you are mapping single files rather than whole parent directory - maybe this is the case.

Comment: it may be the case, I edited the question and added the screen shot, but still have no clear idea how to setup that, because I've tried in many ways.

Comment: could you try to point ```/Users/jfernandez/Sites/dev.prize.cod``` to ```/Users/jfernandez/Sites/dev.prize.cod```. I mean whole folder. Usually I map whole folders and everything works fine.

Comment: yeap, nothing happens :( I even started the server with the button on my phpstorm and start the debbuger with my chrome button and nothing.

Comment: even if I set xdebug_break() it does nothing...

Comment: could you map as I said before, reload phpstorm, activate debuging, do break point in phptest.php - will it work? if yes try to put breakpoint in other part

Comment: Thanks!!! It works, the problem was that I've been configured my project to exclude index.php from debbug so it never reach that, now I deleted that and it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further or similar problems, my error was that i added index.php to my excluded paths and because of that I was never be able to debug, I deleted it and now it works fine.

> especial thanks to Rafail Akhmetshin for his patience help.

Resume:

- Check for exclude paths
- Start debugging with phpStorm button
- Make sure you are listening on the port

as a note point
make sure to check/uncheck

*break at first line on php code*

and *break on first line when no mapping*